# getting csrf working expressjs angularjs nginx

Tags: angularjs, nginx, express, csrf

I'm having trouble setting up (understanding?) csrf protection. My setup is nginx serving static files with expressjs for api calls and angularjs front end. All calls to /api/* are sent to express, anything else is handled by nginx.

I have my login system setup and working fine (without csrf protection). I used the example here ( http://mircozeiss.com/using-csrf-with-express-and-angular/ ) but I keep getting 403 forbidden. (once in a while the login works, till i logout and re-login).

Here's my relevant code:

//nginx

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name login.example.dev;
root /home/example/www/login/pub;
index index.html;

location /api {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
    proxy_pass_header X-XSRF-TOKEN;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
}

location / {
    if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_=(.*)") {
            rewrite ^ /snapshots/$1;
    }
    try_files snapshots$request_uri.html $uri /index.html;
}
}
```

//server.js

```
var config=require('./config.js');
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var RedisStore=require('connect-redis')(express);
var member=require('./routes/member.js');
var auth=require('./routes/auth.js');
var app = express();

app.configure(function(){

    app.enable('trust proxy');
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || config.app.port);
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.session({
    proxy:true,
      secret: config.session.secret,
      store: new RedisStore({db:config.session.redis.db,prefix:config.session.redis.prefix}),
      key: config.session.key,
      cookie:{
        domain:config.session.domain,
        maxAge:config.session.maxAge
      }
    }));

    app.use(express.csrf());
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
          res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', req.csrfToken(),{httpOnly:true,domain:'.example.dev'});
          next();
    });
    app.use(app.router);
});

app.get(config.app.prefix+'/member/get-data.json',restrict,member.getData);
app.post(config.app.prefix+'/auth/login',auth.login);
app.get(config.app.prefix+'/auth/logout', auth.logout);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});

function restrict(req,res,next){
        if(config.session.dataKey in req.session){
            var d=req.session[config.session.dataKey];
            req.session.regenerate(function(err){
                if(err){
                    console.log('Err regen session');
                }else{
                    req.session[config.session.dataKey]=d;
                    next();
                }
            });
        }else{
            req.session.destroy();
            res.json(401,{"msg":"not logged in."});
        }

}
```

//angularjs

```
var loginCtrl = lmu.controller('LoginCtrl',['$scope','$http','User','$location',
function($scope,$http,User,$l){

    $scope.cred={};


    $scope.login=function(){
        $http.post('/api/auth/login',$scope.cred).then(function(res){
                User.data=res.data;
                $l.path('/account');
        },function(e){
                User.data=e.data;
        });
    };
```

}]);

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. You are using `session.regenerate()` to destroy the old session (I think this is good practice to avoid session fixatation) but you also destroy the secret of the XSRF token with this call.
I first tried to set the XSRF cookie in the callback of `session.regenerate()` but this won't work because the secret does not get created again.

What you need instead is a GET request after the login request. Then a new XSRF secret will be generated and the correct token set in the cookie.

And you should make sure that there are GET request going through node.js because all HTTP methods except for HEAD, OPTIONS and GET are CSRF protected. So you cannot set a cookie there.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll mess around with it a bit more and let ya know how it goes.